# How do I look for an element with getElementById outside of the js file my code is in?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `document.getElementById` in a .js file external to my .html file. What word would I use instead of `document` to access it? 
I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Comment: If your js file is linked to the html file, then you can still use it.

Comment: What do you mean by external file ? Are you importing the JS file into your HTML ?

Comment: you need to import your js in that html to use it.

Comment: are you using any framework as frontend?

Comment: It is not about words - its about references behind those words. If you cant access DOM-Objects, no other word helps. It is like using the kitchen without beeing in the kitchen - ignoring iot for once. You have to bring your code into the correct context.

Comment: And what happens if you try to use `document.getElementById`? Do you get an error message, or does something unexpected happen and if so what is it?

Comment: If your question was answered by any of the below, you can click the "check mark"  on the answer to close this question. There's no need to change the title explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Include your JS file into your HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-your-js-file"></script>
```

Then just use `document.getElementById` inside of this JS file, it should work fine.

Comment: according to your edit in original question you mentioned the error message throwing exception on 'addEventListener'. it looks problem is not in document, problem is in getElementById, make sure element with such id exists inside of your html

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<script src='path-to-file.js'></script>` in the body section, not the head.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='path-to-js.js'>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And yes, I know I'm the person that posted this, but I figured it out.